# IntelliJ Ultimate cannot generate code from SAP PI WSDL file

Tags: intellij-idea, soap, sap-pi, sap-xi

Our version of PI doesn't support REST web services, so we consume their SOAP web services and provide rest web service to provide REST web service support to the external entities.

I have SAP-PI WSDL file which we used to import in Eclipse that generates 9 java class files

```
DT_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_RQ
DT_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_RQRecordset
DT_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_RS
DT_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_RSRecordset
SI_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_OUT
SI_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_OUTBindingStub
SI_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_OUTProxy
SI_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_OUTService
SI_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_OUTServiceLocator
```

but when I import that WSDL file in IntelliJ it is not generating 1 java class file.

`SI_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_OUTProxy`

This java class is missing in IntelliJ.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: No error in idea.log.

Comment: Can you please provide correct steps to import SAP-PI WSDL in IntelliJ because in 1 project I am able to import but in another project, I am unable to import WSDL.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java

Comment: Please check error in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in..."). It might be some issue with project dependencies: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000080430-Generate-Wsdl-from-Java-Code-throwing-error

Comment: I have followed the same mentioned steps but I am still facing the same error.